# Error installing quandl with pip on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, quandl

here is the error that I keep getting. I keep trying to install the 
quandl modulen and keep running into this same error. I have tried looking into some other questions but they do not provide any good solutions. I tried looking through the errors but I already have openssl installed.

```
Collecting quandl
  Downloading Quandl-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from quandl)
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 1.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Collecting more-itertools (from quandl)
  Downloading more-itertools-2.2.tar.gz
Collecting ndg-httpsclient (from quandl)
  Downloading ndg_httpsclient-0.4.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from quandl)
Collecting inflection>=0.3.1 (from quandl)
  Downloading inflection-0.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting cryptography>=1.3 (from pyOpenSSL->quandl)
  Downloading cryptography-1.4.tar.gz (399kB)
    100% |################################| 409kB 906kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.14->quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.3->pyOpenSSL->quandl)
Installing collected packages: cryptography, pyOpenSSL, more-itertools, ndg-httpsclient, inflection, quandl
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wm_qxhdb/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hyncpopk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/x509
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_openssl.c:429:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
     #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                                  ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wm_qxhdb/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hyncpopk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wm_qxhdb/cryptography/
```

I am new to ubuntu and linux so I dont know if there is something vital that I am missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are just missing openssl

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

I don't think pip can get that dependency

Comment: thank you so much. Doing **sudo apt-get install libssl-dev** and then re-attempting **sudo pip install quandl** working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

in regards to the Quandl module problem I think it is much easier to use Conda:

1. Install Anaconda. (search how- very easy)
2. use conda  install quandl.
3. on my device I used (import Quandl) and it worked

   sometimes you need to use (import quandl)